# Having trouble with nth-child() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

For a shopfront I'm building a simple selector that allows showing and hiding elements based on their class.

I'm using the nth-child() selector to add a class to every 3rd element, but even though the selector does work in showing and hiding elements, my script doesn't add the class to the third element after making a selection.

The code I'm using is quite big (and can definitely be optimized) so for an example of what I mean, [please take a look at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXGrA/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the HTML, "Show only cat 15" should show 6, 7, 8 and "Show only cat 12" should show everything else, right? It looks like it's working...

Comment: Apologies, I should've been more clear in my question: The selection part of the script works, but if you click 'Show only cat 15', the second element gets the 'product_item_last' class, when it should be the third. I can't figure out why that is happening.

Comment: Are you trying to get the 3rd item, or the "last" item?

Comment: I'm trying to get every third item of whatever selection has been made by clicking one of the categories.

Comment: Even though only 6, 7, and 8 are showing, the remaining `<div>`s are still present... So, "6" is still a 3rd child.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. As Torsten has pointed out below, I misunderstood what nth-child does. Do you know of any easy way of achieving what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what nth-child does.

You expect `.myclass:nth-child(3n)` to select each 3rd occurrence of `.myclass`.

What it really does is select each `nth-child` element of it's parent node regardless of class. It basically acts as a combined selector. In your case

> select each third element that also has the class .myclass

In your case you should use:

```
$(".myclass").each(function(index, item){
    if (index % 3 == 0) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

Comment: Aha! Yeah, I see now. Do you if there's an easy way of selecting each third element of a class?

Comment: I added that to the answer as well. There is also the `$.fn.eq(n)` method but it only allows you to select a single item. So you'd need to loop through them anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sJbjw/)

Your code modified..
Replaced Line

```
 jQuery('.' + className).parent().children('.' + className + ':nth-child(3n) a').addClass('product_item_last');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You're code worked in the Jsfiddle but I couldn't get it to work in my project, so I'm awarding Torsten with the answer.